# Install ubuntu on ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I have hp laptop with intel processor with Ubuntu 14.10 preinstalled in it which is customized. I want to remove that customization and make it original as earlier. SO I want to reinstall Ubuntu in it. Please send me a link to download Ubuntu and install it on Ubuntu os (for reinstallation).

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Ubuntu's system files may sometimes be the quickest way to solve a problem.  See this

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

Answer (score 0):

You could burn an Ubuntu ISO image in a USB with Universal USB Installer in Windows. Or you could burn the ISO from Ubuntu with either the GUI or using "dd" command from the terminal, though I can't remember the syntax now, but it is easy.
Nevertheless, just upgrading it might be quicker.
I can't provide links because I'm answering from a cell phone...
I hope it helped though.